# Reading and writing the common data

Tags: database-design, performance, sql-server-2008-r2, locking

I have a couple tables and application service that intensively inserts, updates its. From the other hand some client application have to read data using those tables. Sometimes client application gets timeout exceptions because of locks this shared data. What the common or maybe non-ordinal solution to separate intensively modified data and fast reading the same one. By the way, data can be *consistent* but can be delayed in time for 10-20 seconds (for example). OLAP cannot be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Snapshot or Read Committed Snapshot isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130975.aspx) for your reads.

> When a row versioning-based isolation level is enabled, the Database
>   Engine maintains versions of each row that is modified. Applications
>   can specify that a transaction use the row versions to view data as it
>   existed at the start of the transaction or query instead of protecting
>   all reads with locks. **By using row versioning, the chance that a read
>   operation will block other transactions is greatly reduced**.

Alternatively:

- Read less. If the nature of the application and data is such that you can tolerate a 10-20 seconds delay, cache the response and returned the cached result until your next successful read.
- Use replication to distribute data to a set of read-only slaves.
- Fix your application. Timeout implies long running transaction; occasionally necessary but typically a design flaw.

Comment: Such is the nature of transaction isolation, a trade between concurrency and consistency. Are you using the default read committed isolation level? Welcome to a world of inconsistency.

Comment: @garik: snapshot isolation does not cause inconsistencies in selects. I wrote the article you are quoting, and I did not mean that. On the contrary, snapshot isolation prevents inconsistencies in selects. Can you elaborate what in the article is misleading?